# How to render React component which uses portals

Tags: reactjs

I have a button which has the following `onClick` action:

```
let linkEditor = new LinkEditor({
    view: view,
    href: "",
    title: "",
    validateLink: null,
});

linkEditor.render();
showModal(document.querySelector("#modal-base") as HTMLElement);
```

where `LinkEditor` uses portals as below:

```
export class LinkEditor extends React.Component {
    hrefInput: HTMLInputElement | null = null;
    textInput: HTMLInputElement | null = null;
    saveBtn: HTMLButtonElement | null = null;
    hrefError: HTMLParagraphElement | null = null;
    view: EditorView | null = null;

    title: string = "";
    href: string = "";
    validateLink: any;

    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);
        this.validateLink = props.validateLink;
        this.view = props.view;
        this.title = props.title;
        this.href = props.href;
    }

    render(): React.ReactNode {
        let editor = (
            <form className="mt6 bt bb bc-black-400 js-link-editor">
                <div className="d-flex fd-column gsy gs8 p12">
                    <div className="flex--item">
                        <label htmlFor="link-editor-href-input" className="s-label mb4">
                            {_t("link_editor.href_label")}
                        </label>
                        <input
                            id="link-editor-href-input"
                            className="s-input js-link-editor-href"
                            type="text"
                            name="href"
                            value={this.href}
                            aria-describedby="link-editor-href-error"
                            ref={(c) => (this.hrefInput = c)}
                        />
                        <p
                            id="link-editor-href-error"
                            className="s-input-message mt4 d-none js-link-editor-href-error"
                            ref={(c) => (this.hrefError = c)}
                        ></p>
                    </div>

                    <div className="flex--item">
                        <label htmlFor="link-editor-text-input" className="s-label mb4">
                            {_t("link_editor.text_label")}
                        </label>
                        <input
                            id="link-text-href-input"
                            className="s-input js-link-editor-text"
                            type="text"
                            value={this.title}
                            name="text"
                            ref={(c) => (this.textInput = c)}
                        />
                    </div>

                    <div className="flex--item">
                        <button
                            className="s-btn s-btn__primary js-link-editor-save-btn"
                            type="submit"
                            disabled
                            ref={(c) => (this.saveBtn = c)}
                        >
                            ${_t("link_editor.save_button")}
                        </button>
                        <button className="s-btn" type="reset">
                            ${_t("link_editor.cancel_button")}
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        );

        return ReactDOM.createPortal(
            editor,
            document.getElementById("link-editor")!
        );
    }
```

I thought that when I call `render()` method, this LinkEditor will be created inside `link-editor` div (which already exists in the DOM) but nothing has changed. What should I change to make it works so that before I call `showModal`, this content will be rendered inside DOM?